# Trying to plot using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, function

as usual I feel stupid because I feel that it should be easy but... well here I am...

I want to plot this function using tikz : x/3.6 + (x^2)/155

So I tried this :

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale =1.2]
        \tkzInit[xmin=-10,xmax=140,ymin = -10, ymax=170,xstep=20, ystep=20 ]
        \tkzGrid
        \tkzAxeXY
        \draw[thick, smooth, samples=100, color=red] plot  (\x,{\x/3.6 + (\x)^2 /155});     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and here's my result :
[image]

Obviously that's not what it should be or at least not what I want it to be... Could someone point my mistakes ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: I recommand not using `tkz-fct` to plot this simple function, because you need to install and run gnuplot to achieve your goal (you may read the documentation, even if it's written in french). You can plot this either in plain Ti*k*Z or using `pgfplot`, it would be much easier.

Comment: I tried to read the documentation (French isn't an obstacle, it's my native language :) ) but I must admit I didn't understand everything...  and I couldn't replicate some of the examples of the documentation. The function often plots as a line instead of a curve.
That said, I am definitely open to plot this using plain tikz ... but I don't know how

Comment: @SebGlav I did another read of the beginning of the documentation of tkz-fct and I realised that I don't use anything of the tkz-fct package since \tkzInit, \tkzGrid and \tkzAxeXY are all defined in tkz-base. So I'm already trying to plot this using only Tikz... Any idea of what I'm missing ?

Comment: @SebGlav You're right about gnuplot and pgfplot. If I have time, I'll replace gnuplot with Lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `\tkzFct` . This macro takes into account the values of xstep and ystep

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale =1.2]
        \tkzInit[xmin=-10,xmax=140,ymin = -10, ymax=170,xstep=20, ystep=20 ]
        \tkzGrid
        \tkzAxeXY
        \tkzFct[thick, smooth, samples=100, color=red,domain=-10:140]{\x/3.6 + (\x*\x) /155}   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works ! Any idea why it didn't work using Tikz ?

Comment: @Kawahiem   you need to adapt \x  with xstep and f(x) with ystep.